# what is the difference between 2 Windows phone 8.0 SDKs

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm going to learn to develop WP app. I installed Visual Studio 2013. VS 2013 have an option to install WP 8.0 SDK. And I knew the site (http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk) has a link to download WP 8.0 SDk. Help me about difference between them. Do I need to install them all for my purpose?

Comment: If you have VS 2013 Ultimate (maybe also Premium/Professional), you may install the PhoneTools (including SDK) like you said and you will be fine developing for WP. I think, the version from dev.windowsphone.com you mentioned includes the WP-VisualStudio-Express IDE, which is just for developing apps for WP and much less wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Visual Studio 2013, there is no difference between these two methods of installing the WP8 SDK. It was added as an optional component when installing Visual Studio 2013 for convenience.

Be aware, it's not possible to develop for Windows Phone 7 (or open existing projects) with Visual Studio 2013 + WP8 SDK.